# Know how function with external methods was called without editing it in Python

Tags: python, oop, testing, pytest

I couldn't find an answer so I ask:

Let's say I have a file with these functions:

```
def method_1(param1, param2):
    send_email(param1)
    print('method_1 is done')               
    
def method_2(param1, param2):
    new_param = external_method(param1)
    method_1(new_param['key'], param2)
    print('method_2 is done')
```

They are part of some MVC framework, and I'm trying to write a **test**, so changing the functions is not an option. The test would be to check whether the sent email is correct.

`external_method()` depends on an external API, so I don't know what it will return, meaning that whatever I write to mock it, it will be inaccurate to a real-life setting.

All I know about `external_method`'s result is that it should be in the form of a `dict` and contain a key called `'key'`

**Without editing the code above**, is there a way to know if `send_email` inside `method_1` was called with the right `param1`? Meaning that the email contains what I expect it to contain based on the origin of `param1`.

I know that I could use a runtime debugger but I was wondering if there are other solutions.

Comment: The builtin libraries [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html) and [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) may help you.

Comment: What do you consider the right parameters? Are you looking for code coverage? Is your question on checking whether the function was called, whether the function was executed, or whether the parameters were correct?

Comment: Collecting [coverage (3rd-party)](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/coverage-5.2.1/) is often extremely powerful with `unittest`

Comment: You can use `unittest` or `pytest` with [mock.patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch). You patch `method1` (replacing it with a mock), and after calling `method2`, check [assert_called_with](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_with) on the mock.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'll edit the question, there was something missing.

Comment: @ti7 yeah, those were my first places to look in

Comment: @MrBeanBremen that sounds good, but please check the extra line I added. Can a mock replicate `external_method()`?

Comment: How is *mocking* ``external_method`` related to knowing *whether* ``method1`` was called with the right parameters? Are you trying to mock ``external_method`` *so that* ``method1`` is called with the right parameters?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I want to check if `param1` inside `method1` is correct. And the result of `external_method` is what will define that; but I can't mock external_method because it depends on an external service.

Comment: Can you please give a more concrete problem that shows the actual issue? As shown, ``method_1`` accepts anything as ``param1``. What do you consider an *incorrect* value? Those that result in an exception? Those that lead to unexpected output?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi sure, I'll elaborate some more. Thank you

Comment: @MrBeanBremen I'll add some more context

Comment: Well, after the update it still looks as you have to mock `external_method` to return a dict with a known `key` entry, and mock `send_email` to check how it is called (using `assert_called_once_with`).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen that could work, but then if I want `method_2` to run, then I'd have to mock or recreate `external_method` somehow within it. Is that viable?

Comment: Sorry, don't understand that. I would suggest you to try to write such a test, and if you get problems, come back with your test code, so we can help you with the concrete problems. Anyway it is a good idea first to try out something to get a feeling for the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out:

> Without editing the code above, is there a way to know if send_email
> inside method_1 was called with the right param1?

**No.** This requires us being able to check the email methods; so it's a different scope.